# Terminal emulator capable of selecting with keyboard only

Tags: terminal-emulator

I'd like to replicate `tmux` copy-mode without using a multiplexer.

As far as I know `xterm` does not have this capability. Do other terminal emulators support such mode?

An example:

- `Ctrl-[` to enter copy-mode
- `vi` cursor motions (e.g. `?` to search backwards)
- `v` - begin selection
- `y` - yank as X11 selection (shared between windows)
- `p` - paste from X11 selection

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the only one capable of this is [Termite](https://github.com/thestinger/termite/).

Answer (score 0):

**Keyboard Selection Feature**

Has:

- [rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html) + [addon](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls/#keyboard-select)

Doesn't Have:

- [Gnome Terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/txt-copy-paste.html.en)
- [Tilix](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/issues/1305)
- [Alacritty](https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty/issues/262)

It looks like majority of terminals are based on VTE, so patching VTE here - https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78291 - is a way to make it feature generally available for developers.